# System of differential equations in Maple

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, maple

I have problems entering a system of differential equations to Maple 13. Equations are:

$x' = -4x + 2y$
$y' = 5x - 4y$

Solve for $x = 0, y = 0$

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=1377)?

Comment: @J. M. yes, the problem is, that examples contain y(t), x(t), but in my case it is x(y)=... y(x)=...

Comment: ...there is (supposed to be) an implied independent variable for your functions. So, something like $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}x(t)=-4x(t)+2y(t)$ and similarly for your second equation.

Comment: When you write "solve for $x=0,y=0$", I presume you meant to give an initial condition, e.g. $x(0) = 0, y(0) = 0$?

Comment: @Sam It is as written in condition. Solve in dead point environment (x = 0, y = 0). I do not actually understand why there should be independent variable (maybe because I am not math student)

Comment: @Kukmedis : I have never come across the phrase "dead point environment" before.  Can you give some idea of what this means, perhaps by citing the definition from your class?

Comment: The reason that J.M. and I think there should be an independent variable in here, is that the notation is unclear.  When you use a $'$ to indicate the derivative, it must be clear from context what variable you are differentiating with respect to.  I think a first thing you need to do is to determine what exactly the question is asking for.  What characterizes the solution (x, y) that you are supposed to find?  What is it, what properties does it have, if someone hands you a candidate how do you tell if it is what you want?

Comment: @Sam. Yes indeed there was independant variable. I have hard time translating math and physics into english. I am not math nor physics student and these differential equations are giving me a headache...

Comment: @Kukmedis: Have you got your answer on this problem at last??

Comment: @Kukmedis: Did you see my answer below? :)

Answer (score 7):

I have two ways for solving this system of equations using the [dsolve](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=dsolve) command:

1)

```
sys := diff(x(t), t) = -4*x(t)+2*y(t), diff(y(t), t) = 5*x(t)-4*y(t):
f := {x(t), y(t)}:
dsolve({sys, x(0) = 0, y(0) = 0}, f);
```

2)

```
sys := [diff(x(t), t) = -4*x(t)+2*y(t), diff(y(t), t) = 5*x(t)-4*y(t)]:
p := dsolve(sys):
a1 := subs(x(t) = 0, t = 0, p[1]):
a2 := subs(y(t) = 0, t = 0, p[2]):
solve({a1, a2}, {_C1, _C2});
```